# Cannot import images in react, Module Not Found

Tags: reactjs

my react app cannot find my image file. I have tried multiple ways of importing.
I am importing this in my App.js

```
import logo from "./images/companyLogo.png"

<img src={logo} />
```

```
<img src={require("./images/companyLogo.png")} />
```

I even saw a way by putting the images file in the public folder and import it like following: (don't know why this worked for some people)

```
<img src="images/companyLogo.png" />
```

I have checked my directory it looks fine.

[image]

[image]
Please help T_T

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not adding your images in public folder and refer it easily in your jsx?

Comment: Im not sure if I understand your question. I was taught to put files and folders in src folder and not public folder

Comment: Which component in which this image being used? If it's something in components folder, path of the image is wrong. Path can be ../images/...

Comment: This image is being used inside App.js component, but I found a better way of importing images now. Just use it as background image in css

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a Webpack loader in your webpack config to import images or other such files.

[Webpack File Loader](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/)

Comment: are there way that I don't need this file loader?

Comment: Not if you want to import them like that

Comment: how come when others on youtube importing images like this, they never mention a word about this web pack thing? Is this web pack configuration suppose to be default when react app was created?

Comment: File loaders are not included by default as many dont import images as such except maybe for SVG files.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MRbqLWAwqko this person didn't do web pack either and he's importing images the same way i did, but why his worked?

Comment: Not sure why that guy didnt speak about webpack loaders. Im also not sure why you have to import if like that when you can just use it like `<img src="images/companyLogo.png" />`

Comment: ```<img src="images/companyLogo.png" />``` this method still requires the web pack loader right? I just didn't see anyone on youtube doing it this way

Comment: It does not require a loader as it is compiled inside the browser on runtime.

Comment: I tried your method but it still returns module not found, however, I found a way around it by justing importing images as background image in css and it works fine

Comment: @Haiquan Even better!